# Copying Printer Shortcuts From Windows to Mac

Tags: windows-7, macos, network-printer, right-click

All my school computers have a folder that has the drivers for each printer in the building. If I type up a project or essay on my Mac, I have to transfer the document from my Mac to the school computers to print, which is time consuming and just flat out annoying.

What I want to know, is how can I copy the shortcuts from my schools Windows computers, to my Mac. I thought that I could just archive the folder, and email it to myself, but my school has disabled the ability to right click on all the computers (don't ask me why).

What are some other ways that I can get about copying the folder with the printer drivers onto my Mac? I also can't install programs that require administrative permissions because that's against our ToS, although I know a way to change the administrative password.

Comment: You need the Mac drivers for the printers.  Talk to you school IT and see if they can supply them.

Comment: Windows shortcuts won't work on a Mac, even if you can get them over, they'll just be files named [shortcut].lnk The drivers themselves won't be any use on the Mac either. Mac needs Mac drivers - though it already contains drivers for most well-known printers.

Answer (score 0):

You can press CTRL + c to copy after selecting files and then use CTRL + v to paste them to destination.

In additon you can use File menu and select Copy in Windows Explorer.

Another alternative is using Windows button and typing "cmd", ENTER and then using "copy (source) (destination)" command.

Comment: But where would I paste them to? I tried emailing the shortcuts themselves, but of course you can't because they're shortcuts.

Comment: Cannot you use a network connection or removable (USB/DVD) drive to copy files?

Comment: I don't have a USB right now. My 64gb flash drive got stolen.

Comment: Well, you need a "destination" to copy. If source computer has internet access just e-mail the file to yourself, or download the driver from vendor's website using your personal computer.

Comment: I stated above that I can't e-mail it to myself, because you can't e-mail a shortcut. I thought about downloading it from the vendor's website, but I go into 8 classrooms a day, with most of them having 2-4 printers each. That's 16-32 individual printers that I would have to search for. I'd prefer that be last resort.

Comment: That would not be practical. Just talk to the support staff of your school or ask a friend to lend you a USB drive. :)

Comment: I'll try that when I get to school tomorrow.

Comment: How will IntactDev use those Windows printer drivers on their Mac?